# Loading images in vue.js from an API

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Consider this:

- An API loads a manifest of image metadata. The images have an ID, and with another API call returns a base64 image from the DB. The model for the manifest is `attachmentRecord` and the ID is simply a field.
- I would rather not preload these large strings into an array (that would work).

so I have this (which lazy loads on any manifest change):

```
<div v-for="(attachment, index) in  attachmentRecord" :key="index">
    <img :src="fetchImage(attachment.id)" />
</div>
```

`fetchimage()` is a wrapper for an axios function which returns back from a promise. (writing this from memory):

```
this.axios({
    method: "get",
    url: url,
 }).then(res => res.data)
   .catch(() => {
      alert("Unable to load raw attachment from this task and ID");
    });
 }
```

Now, the network calls go thru fine, the ID passes in correctly, I can see the base 64data, but they don't seem to make it to wrapper function or the src attribute. It always comes up blank. I tried wrapping it in another promise,only to get a promise back to the src attribute. What would be a best practice for this situation in Vue?

Ok, so far I made these changes with Constantin's help:
I tried to strip it down without a helper function:

Vue template Code:

```
<div v-for="(attachment, index) in  attachmentRecord" :key="index">
<img :src="getAttachmentFromTask(attachment.id)" />
```

base method:

```
async getAttachmentFromTask(attachmentID) {
  if (!attachmentID) alert("Unknown Attachment!");
  let sendBack = "";
  let url = "/server/..."

  await this.axios({
    method: "get",
    url: url
  })
    .then(res => {
      sendBack = res.data;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      alert("Unable to load raw attachment from this task and ID");
    });
  // >>>>>>>>>alerts base64 correctly; Vue loads [object Promise] in img
  alert(sendBack);
  return sendBack; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Vue doesn't handle `async` / `await` as well as I thought. Therefore, you have to save the image data to each attachment in `attachmentRecord`. This `getAttachmentFromTask` method now handles this when accessed the first time and populates a `data` property for the corresponding attachment object. On successive calls, that property is returned if it is already populated. *Note the usage of `Vue.set()` because the property is not available in the initial data, but we want it to be reactive.* You can even set up a fallback image like a loader, see the shortly flickering SO logo without text before the larger logo appears:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    attachmentRecord: [{
      id: 1
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    getAttachmentFromTask(attachmentIndex, attachmentID) {
      let record = this.attachmentRecord[attachmentIndex];
      if (!record.data) {
        Vue.set(record, 'data', null);
        axios.get('https://kunden.48design.de/stackoverflow/image-base64-api-mockup.json').then((result) => {
          Vue.set(record, 'data', result.data);
        });
      }
      return this.attachmentRecord[attachmentIndex].data;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(attachment, index) in  attachmentRecord" :key="index">
    <img :src="getAttachmentFromTask(index, attachment.id) || 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png'" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**old answer:** (Unfortunately doesn't work that way with Vue currently)

Axios requests are asynchronous by default. So the function doesn't wait for `then()` to return the value. You could add the `async` keyword before your `fetchImage` function name and add the `await` keyword before `this.axios`. Then make the `then` callback assign the return value to a variable in the `fetchImage` function scope and have the function return it.

```js
async fetchImage() {
    let returnValue;
    await this.axios({
        method: "get",
        url: url,
     }).then(res => { returnValue = res.data; })
       .catch(() => {
          alert("Unable to load raw attachment from this task and ID");
        });
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved part of it actually. I will mark as solved. I still can't get the src attribute to update. I can break in the `then()` call, return a value, but nothing is returned to src attribute. All I  (fetchimage changed to getSrcImage)  `getSrcImage: function(id) {
      let that = this;

      that.getAttachmentFromTask(id).then(str => {
        return str;
      });` also tried: `function(id) {
      let that = this;
       let buffer = "";
      that.getAttachmentFromTask(id).then(str => {
        buffer = str;
      });
      return buffer;
    }`

Comment: You're missing the async/await again!

Comment: `getSrcImage: async function(id) { let returnValue; await this.getAttachmentFromTask(id).then(str => { returnValue = str; }); return returnValue; }` - `getAttachmentFromTask`'s definition will have to have the `async` keyword as well.

Comment: src= [object Promise] when I change to `getSrcImage: async function(id) {
      let that = this;
      let buffer = "";
      await that.getAttachmentFromTask(id).then(str => {
        buffer = str;
        
      });
      return buffer;     
    }` I had this issue when I experimented before. Something simple?

Comment: I pasted in yours as is and got the promise in src.

Comment: Then `getAttachmentFromTask`  seems to return a promise, not a string

Comment: If I break in the "then" I can see a base64 string....I have to look further. Similar code has no problem updating an array of base 64's and showing them as images.

Comment: How are you checking for the correct string? `console.log(str)`? If that returns the base64 string, then it should work indeed. That's strange... If you haven't figured it out, I'll try to build a working example tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the original question, I took out the helper method. Should be easy to test. I posted in a comment what is happening.

Comment: You can give `return (await this.axios({ method: "get", url: url })).data` a try.

Comment: Same thing, promise. I traced it into the vue code. Calling `_vm.getAttachmentFromTask(attachment.id)` returns a promise.

Comment: I completely revamped my answer and had to take a slightly different route. But it comes with a fully working snippet now.

Comment: Dankeschön! I'm aware of SET, it is usually for making some array operations reactive. I marked it as answered, but it essentially caching the strings.I guess that is a limitation in vue.I also understand async/await now perfectly!